# MYSQL:Where not exists syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know how to use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` in mysql for the following query.It gives mysql syntax error.I tried all possible ways but nothing helps.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
        (
         SELECT l.pid 
           FROM lineitem l 
          WHERE l.oid IN (
                          SELECT o1.oid 
                            FROM customer c 
                                    JOIN ( 
                                          SELECT o.oid,
                                                 o.cid 
                                            FROM orders o
                                         ) o1 
                                         ON c.cid=o1.cid 
                                        AND c.city='Newark'
                          ) 
       GROUP BY l.pid
        ) 
       WHERE not exists (
                        SELECT l.pid 
                          FROM lineitem l 
                         WHERE l.oid IN (
                                         SELECT o1.oid 
                                           FROM customer c 
                                                    JOIN (
                                                          SELECT o.oid,
                                                                 o.cid 
                                                            FROM orders o
                                                          )o1 
                                                          ON c.cid=o1.cid
                                                          AND c.city<>'Newark'
                                         )
                        )
       )
```

My tables are:
customer(cid,name,city,state)
orders(oid,cid,date)
product(pid,price,productname)
lineitem(lid,number,oid,pid,totalprice)

I want to select all the products bought only by persons in Newark.My logic is (select products bought by customers in Newark)-(select products bought by all other customers).I am using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` because difference keyword is not available in mysql.

Comment: Can you make some effort to better format your query?

Comment: And this syntax error is...?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where not exists (select l.pid from lineitem l where l.oid in (select o1.oid fro' at line 1 this s my exact error message

Comment: Not surprised, I can't make head not tail of it either. Perhaps giving your columns meaningful names would help.Some vague clue as to the intended output would be good as well.

Comment: So you want products that were only ordered from  customers in Newark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a better solution:

```
SELECT ProductID FROM (
       SELECT p.pid ProductID
         FROM lineitem l
              JOIN product p
                   ON l.pid = p.pid
              JOIN orders o
                   ON l.oid = o.oid
        WHERE o.cid IN (
              SELECT c.cid 
                FROM customer c 
               WHERE c.city = 'Newark'
              )
        ) t1 
WHERE ProductID NOT IN (
      SELECT p.pid 
        FROM lineitem l
             JOIN product p
                  ON l.pid = p.pid
         JOIN orders o
              ON l.oid = o.oid
       WHERE o.cid IN (
             SELECT c.cid 
               FROM customer c 
              WHERE c.city <> 'Newark'
             )
      );
```

I also believe, that because of less nested queries, that one would be better on perfomance.

And the problem in your query is parenthesis. You saying

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ( 
         ( ... ) 
        WHERE NO EXISTS 
         ( ... ) 
       );
```

while you should say

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ( ... ) 
WHERE NO EXISTS ( ... );
```

---

Since it works, here's a further simplification (removing the derived table `t1` and the `JOIN product p` in the 2nd part subquery):

```
SELECT p.pid ProductID
  FROM lineitem l
       JOIN product p
            ON l.pid = p.pid
       JOIN orders o
            ON l.oid = o.oid
 WHERE o.cid IN (
       SELECT c.cid 
         FROM customer c 
        WHERE c.city = 'Newark'
       )
  AND p.pid NOT IN (
      SELECT l.pid 
        FROM lineitem l
         JOIN orders o
              ON l.oid = o.oid
       WHERE o.cid IN (
             SELECT c.cid 
               FROM customer c 
              WHERE c.city <> 'Newark'
             )
      );
```

Comment: Thanks your's works fine but why where not exists doesn't work whats wrong in that

Comment: Where not exists is a correlated subquery. ie query whether each product ordered from Newark was ordered from anywhere else.

Comment: @user1613360 Try to just remove first and last parenthesis from your original query and see if it would work

Comment: @user1613360 you welcome. And I still suggest you prefer my solution, because of the perfomance

Answer (score 0):

```
Select l.pid from lineitem l
inner join Orders o on l.oid = o.oid
inner join Customers c on o.cid = c.cid  and c.city = 'Newark'
where not in 
(
Select ol.pid from lineitem ol
inner join Orders oo on ol.oid = oo.oid
inner join Customers oc on oo.cid = oc.cid  and oc.city <> 'Newark'
)
```

I think...
Where not exists would require a correlated subquery.

Comment: Thanks but your query give me this    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'in ( Select ol.pid from lineitem ol inner join Orders oo on ol.oid = oo.oid inn' at line 4

Comment: `where not in (` is wrong, there is a column missing after the `where`